# Which Smirnov is behind the Smirnov topology?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, math-history

Good old Steen and Seebach discuss the Smirnov deleted sequence topology in their Counterexamples in Topology (2nd ed. 1978).

This is also reported as the $K$-topology, in e.g. Wikipedia etc.

However, none of the sources that I've found tell us which particular Smirnov is behind it.

I am guessing it's **Yurii Mikhailovich Smirnov** as of all the Smirnovs I know of in mathematics, he is the one who has greatest involvement in topology.

(For example: Vladimir Ivanovich is known for a 5-volume textbook, and Nikolai Vasilyevich made a name for himself in statistics.)

Yurii Mikhailovich is of course the mathematician whose name is associated with the Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorem, so it's more than plausible it's the same one.

Can anyone point me towards a source that can confirm this?

Comment: It's probably not Yakov Smirnov but I suppose you can't be too sure

Comment: Considering the provenance of Tom Lehrer, I can't fault your logic. :-)

Comment: He must have been active around 1929, as he's credited with the example in a paper from around that time. The metrisation theorem is from the fifties.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Any source for that? The metrization paper includes this example of a topology, sure, but the 1951 paper does not actually make any reference to any 1929 paper. My Russian's a but rusty so it will take effort to make sense of the 1951 paper.

Comment: It’s in Mémoire sur des espaces topologiques compacts. By Alexandroff & Urysohn and they credit it to Smirnov IiRC that’s a French paper do a lot easier.

Comment: Got it, thanks, it's referenced in the bibliography of S&S.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Yurii Mikhailovich Smirnov was born in 1921, so now I'm not sure this *is* the same Smirnov, if it dates from back then. Thanks for the pointer, further research to be done.

Comment: It's probably Yurii, in view of Brian's find. The paper by A&U contains many examples (the double circle and the lexicographically ordered square and some other examples in S&S come from that paper too), it need not be for the deleted sequence topology (which is not even (locally) compact, so fits better in the metrisation context (as an example why we need $T_3$ and not just $T_2$ etc.).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Easy enough to read it in French if you can actually find a copy of the thing in the first place. So while some topological concepts indeed seem to be discussed in that Alexandroff and Urysohn paper, as there's no immediate evidence that it ever included the Smirnov topology, I'll disregard it until I get some better info. Thx.

Comment: Willard has it as Ex. 14.2 without reference. The paper (translated version) is in the bibliography though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is Yurii Mikhailovich Smirnov: the space is Example $1$ in his paper [О МЕТРИЗАЦИИ ТОПОЛОГИЧЕСКИХ ПРОСТРАНСТВ](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/d1a0f40646f1a47497b9e81be655a56b/rm6904.pdf) (On metrization of topological spaces), *Uspekhi Matem. Nauk*, 1951, **6**, 100-111. It’s on p. 107 at the end of Section 2.

Comment: In light of this and Henno's research, I'll go with this reference. Until I manage to get hold of a copy of the 1929 document and confirm this topology is or is not in there, I'll assume that the 1951 ref is the first time it's detailed. Thx.

Comment: @PrimeMover: My pleasure.

Comment: @PrimeMover It's translated in Smirnov Yu. M. On metrization of topological spaces Amer. Math. Soc. Transl. 8 (Ser. 1) 63–77 (thx to Engelking). Engelking (General Topology 2nd ed.) treats the example in 1.5.6 but gives no reference in the historical notes, which is atypical.

Comment: Yes, that's the 1951 reference, I've got that, that's not a problem, it's the 1929 dissertation I haven't been able to lay my hands on. Besides, all I really need is just confirmation of which Smirnov this topology was named after, and I think it's fair to go with Yu.M.